# WebRTC Support on Chrome Browser in iphone/ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, webrtc

Is WebRTC Supported on Chrome Browser in iPhone/iPad?

Answer (score 23):

No you can't use WebRTC in Chrome in iPhone / iPad because Chrome (and also Firefox) are only some cover over apple WebView (Apple doesn't let to use custom web engine on their platform). Sad is that it isn't clearly informed by Google and Mozilla because some people get confused and said "Yes chrome support WebRTC so it should work on iOS devices". 
Apple has not presented version of their browser and also webview with WebRTC.

Current status of it you could check
http://iswebrtcreadyyet.com/

Comment: Does anyone know current status?

Answer (score 3):

Now Apple announce that IOS11 have supported the webRTC in the mobile safari. Yes, the safari do it. But As the hybrid developer who want to use webRTC in my app, it is difficult to call the getUserMedia(), the return is not exist function, in the WKWebView context. Do the same test in the other 3third IOS browser, such as Chrome for IOS, Firefox for IOS and QQ browser for IOS. All of them have encountered the same issue. So I guess that Apple doesn't let to use custom web engine on their platform, as the above saying.

Comment: see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=752458 -- getUserMedia is not supported in WKWebView.