# WebRTC Supported on Chrome Browser in iPhone/iPad?

Tags: ios, webrtc

We have leveraged WebRTC to build our communication web application, it is not working properly when we tried to access through iPhone or iPad? Do ios support WebRTC?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WebRTC Support on Chrome Browser in iphone/ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39790639/webrtc-support-on-chrome-browser-in-iphone-ipad)

Answer (score 0):

In safari, you can.
But in chrome, not yet.